# Creating an off-canvas menu Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an offcanvas menu for mobile I managed to make the menu slide out and slide the content away however the slide effect is seems to be off as there is a gap when it slides in and out.

https://jsfiddle.net/tg7L44wo/

```js
 

   function openNav() {
      $("#mySidenav").addClass('shifty-show').removeClass('shifty-hidden');
      $("#main").addClass('shifty-content').removeClass('main');
    }
function closeNav() {
  $("#mySidenav").removeClass('shifty-show').addClass('shifty-hidden');
  $("#main").removeClass('shifty-content').addClass('main');
}
```

```css
.main {
  left: 0;
}
.shifty-hidden {
  left: -220px;
}
.shifty-show {
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.shifty-content {
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  left: 198px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#7439e1585a705f4a0033ccc54124cd89

[You can actually do this is Pure CSS!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBWiU_6HLDI)

It's actually really simple.

You start off with a checkbox...

```
<input id="menu" type="checkbox">
```

This will the our menu.

Then you use a label and you give it a for attribute which it's value will be the id of the checkbox. This way when the label is clicked it'll toggle the checkbox.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <label class="fa fa-bars" for="menu"></label>
</a>
```

In this case I want to move the header when checked. So first I'm styling it's position before it's checked. **`NOTE:`** `transition: all ease-in 300ms;` is what creates the slide animation.

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease-in 300ms;
}
```

Then I'm telling the menu that when it's checked to slide the header.

```
#menu:checked ~ header {
  left: 50%;
}
```

It's that simple! I've added the snippet too so you can play around with this more.

```css
body {
  font: 15px arial;
  background: #545454;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.pointer, a, label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fr {
  float: right;
}
header a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
}
header a:hover {
  color: #999;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #7c7c7c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  color: #b5b5b5;
}

/* The menubar */
input[type=checkbox],
#menu {
  display: none;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease-in 300ms;
}
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: 100%;
  padding: 1.04em;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  background: #3f3f3f;
  transition: all ease-in 300ms;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#menu:checked ~ .navbar {
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
#menu:checked ~ header {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="menu" type="checkbox">

<header>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label class="fa fa-bars" for="menu"></label>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
  </a>
</header>

<div class="navbar">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae vel nihil sed, fuga, ad natus magni beatae! Velit, ducimus unde quis necessitatibus, veniam cum fuga libero neque, fugit dolorem, id!
  </p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fr">
    <label for="menu">Close</label>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the value of left in .shifty-hidden class as below:

```
.shifty-hidden{
   left: -198px;
}
```

hope that helps